# Win7/64bit: Notepad++ XML Tools Plugin does not load

Tags: xml, plugins, notepad++

I am having trouble with Notepad++ on my Windows 7, 64-bit machine. I have downloaded the XML tools plugin but cannot get it to run.

I downloaded the .7z extensions from the 64-bit folder: 
28/May/2013 14:22    669 KB    iconv-1.14-win32-x86_64.7z
28/May/2013 14:28    3.4 MB    libxml-2.9.1-win32-x86_64.7z
28/May/2013 14:55    1.0 MB    libxslt-1.1.28-win32-x86_64.7z
28/May/2013 14:55    58 KB     mingwrt-4.8.0-win32-x86_64.7z
29/May/2013 13:38    2.3 MB    openssl-1.0.1e-win32-x86_64.7z
28/May/2013 14:23    129 KB    zlib-1.2.8-win32-x86_64.7z

I unzipped them and they turn into folders. I put all the folders under a new folder ext_libs, and placed this in C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++. I also copied this to C:\Windows\System32, as suggested by another user. Yet when I open Notepad++, all I see under Plugins -> XML Tools is "How to use."

There are other features of the XML Tools that I would like to use rather than TextFX. I would prefer also not to have to run Notepad++ as an Admin to get this to work.

Are these not the right files to use? Where should they go?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar issues but they disappeared after I created a folder XMLTools inside the plugins folder, moved the XMLTools.dll file there and restarted NPP.

Comment: Yep this sorted me out as well. See here for latest methods of installing the plugin in versions of NPP greater than 7.6: https://superuser.com/questions/1396539/xml-tools-for-notepad-libxml-and-or-libxslt-missing/1460224

Answer (score 2):

Follow instruction below, it worked for me in case of 64-bit n++.

1. Downloaded Plugins from this link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XML%20Tools/Xml%20Tools%202.4.9%20Unicode/Xml%20Tools%202.4.9.2%20x64%20Unicode.zip/download
2. Stop notepad++
3. Copy new external dll either into npp main folder (same folder with
   "notepad++.exe") or in %appdata%\Notepad++ folder:

   - libcurl.dll
   - libiconv-2.dll
   - libwinpthread1-dll
   - libxml2-2.dll
   - libxslt-1.dll
   - zlib1.dll``
4. Create Folder "XMLTools" under npp plugins folder.
5. Put XMLTools.dll in npp plugins -> "XMLTools" folder.

After installation in npp main folder, you should have following structure:

````
  [NPP_ROOT_FOLDER]
   ¦   notepad++.exe
   |   libcurl.dll
   ¦   libiconv-2.dll
   ¦   libwinpthread-1.dll
   ¦   libxml2-2.dll
   ¦   libxslt-1.dll
   ¦   zlib1.dll
    +---[plugins/XMLTools/]
           XMLTools.dll```
````

Comment: This worked for me.  I already had this structure (XMLTools.dll Version 2.4.11.0) but it wasn't working until I deleted the existing files, downloaded the files from https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/, then added the downloaded files to NPP_ROOT_FOLDER (XMLTools.dll Version 1.0.0.1).

Answer (score 1):

You have a 32-bit notepad++, but you downloaded the x86_64 extensions.  You need to either install the 64-bit notepad++, or install the 32-bit xml tools.  (app and libraries' bitness needs to match)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10

Notepad++ v7.5.8 (64-bit) (latest as of time of writing)

Download last release of XML tools (Xml Tools 2.4.9.2 x64 Unicode.zip)

[Link to sourceforge xml tools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XML%20Tools/Xml%20Tools%202.4.9%20Unicode/)

Extract the archive and put XMLTools.dll into the plugins directory.

All the files from dependencies folder (libcurl.dll, zlib1.dll, ...etc.) have to be copied over to same directory as your Notepad++ for example "C:\Program Files\Notepad++" if default WITHOUT the "dependencies" folder, otherwise once you restart Notepad++ it'll say the plugin is incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest 64 bit version of Notepad++ from their website. Reinstall latest plugin manager version under plugin manager -> installed. Then install XML Tools via plugin manager.

Comment: From https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.5.1.html :

Note that the most of plugins (including Plugin Manager) are not yet available in x64

Comment: What was the correct answer sir? Please let me know as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Consider these statements

32-bit plugins are not compatible with 64-bit executable
64-bit plugins are not compatible with 32-bit executable

Either go with:

32-bit executable (notepad++.exe) and 32-bit plugins
or
64-bit executable (notepad++.exe) and 64-bit plugins
Note: x86 is another term for 32-bit (means the same thing, in this context at least)